# SKLightNode woes: light not applying to all expected nodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sklightnode

I have a node tree that looks like:

```
LayerWorld
     -> layerBackground  //contains the map tiles
     -> layerUnitSurface //contains all the sprite nodes moving around the map
     -> layerOverlay     //contains the huds, UI buttons etc
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but I also control the positioning of some objects using `.zPosition` according to the following defintions:

```
#define UNITLAYER_ZPOS_PASSENGER    -10
#define UNITLAYER_ZPOS_GHOST        001
#define UNITLAYER_ZPOS_BACK         050
#define UNITLAYER_ZPOS_CITY         100
#define UNITLAYER_ZPOS_FRONT        200
#define UNITLAYER_ZPOS_SMOKE        300
#define UNITLAYER_ZPOS_BLAST        400
#define UNITLAYER_ZPOS_HUD          500
#define UILAYER_ZPOS_BUTTONS        1000
```

In a certain "inspection" mode where the user is focused on a particular sprite, I want to highlight the view. This unit is called the `reconSprite` and is added to the `layerUnitSurface`. I want to dim the entire background map except except for the sprite's immediate vicinity. `SKLightNode` examples showing an illuminated character moving around a dark dungeon is exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm apparently applying the light node incorrectly as I never see any lighting changes in any of my layers. I don't see what I'm doing wrong, though:

```
layerBackground.lightingBitMask = 1;
layerBackground.shadowCastBitMask = 0;
layerBackground.shadowedBitMask = 1;

SKLightNode *intelLightSource = [[SKLightNode alloc] init];
intelLightSource.categoryBitMask = 1;
intelLightSource.falloff = 0.5;
intelLightSource.ambientColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.3 alpha:0.25];
intelLightSource.lightColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.4 alpha:0.8];
intelLightSource.shadowColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.9];

intelLightSource.zPosition = UNITLAYER_ZPOS_SMOKE;
intelLightSource.position = reconSprite.position;
[layerWorld addChild:intelLightSource];
```

I expected this would make the entire map appear dim, with a bright region at `reconSprite.position`. But, there's no visible changes. The entire scene remains fully illuminated.

I know the light source is present, because when I temporarily add:

```
reconSprite.lightingBitMask = 1;
reconSprite.shadowCastBitMask = 1;
reconSprite.shadowedBitMask = 1;
```

The reconSprite is brightened and casts a black shadow.

**Question: why is my `SKLightNode` affecting the `reconSprite` but not the entire `layerBackground`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes do not inherit lighting properties from their parents. So, while I was applying the correct lighting properties to the the background layer, I had to apply the same properties to every tile in that layer. Then it worked as expected.